# Why is my program compiling to weird addresses?

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, c

I'm following Hacking: The Art of Exploitation along with their lessons, and I've hit a roadblock.

When I try to compile the same code they are using, my program will compile to considerably different addresses, making it very hard for me to follow along.

For example, for this same code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static void cleanup(void) __attribute__ ((destructor));
int main() {
 printf("Some actions happen in the main() function..\n");
 printf("and then when main() exits, the destructor is called..\n");
 exit(0);
}
void cleanup(void) {
 printf("In the cleanup function now..\n");
}
```

while their example shows

```
reader@hacking:~/booksrc $ nm ./dtors_sample
080495bc d _DYNAMIC
08049688 d _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_
080484e4 R _IO_stdin_used w _Jv_RegisterClasses
080495a8 d __CTOR_END__
080495a4 d __CTOR_LIST__

080495b4 d __DTOR_END__

080495ac d __DTOR_LIST__
080485a0 r __FRAME_END__
080495b8 d __JCR_END__
080495b8 d __JCR_LIST__
```

mine shows

```
0000000000601048 B __bss_start
000000000040059f t cleanup
0000000000601048 b completed.6972
0000000000601038 D __data_start
0000000000601038 W data_start
00000000004004c0 t deregister_tm_clones
0000000000400530 t __do_global_dtors_aux
```

It's making it impossible for me to follow their format string vulnerability attacks (since you can't save 0x00 in the stack), and I'm getting wildly different results compared to them.

Is there something wrong with my setup? I'm working with a VM (VirtualBox) inside Windows 10. I'm using Ubuntu 14.04.2.

Comment: Read up on ASLR.  https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Address_space_layout_randomization

Comment: The lengths of the addresses hint that the example you're reading was made on a 32-bit system, and you're running a 64-bit system. Better get used to working with those zeroes, or make a 32-bit VM to test on.

Comment: There are a lot of other dependencies like platform, and compiler between what you are using and whatever the author of the book is using.

Comment: @ilkkachu thank you, that was very helpful. I will try to work on their own version of Linux that they provided rather than working on my own VM to avoid this then.